# Ways of breaking melons in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

i am playing on a 1.7.10 minecraft factions server that has disabled pistons' ability of breaking melons. is there any other way of automatically breaking them? perhaps they'd break if another block is placed near them like cacti?

Comment: water maybe? or if you can use the piston to move the block underneath the melon maybe?

Comment: right, I forgot about its inability to hang in the air. thank you!

Comment: I'll post an answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Melon blocks (quite unlike their stems) are fairly resilient to most 'damaging influences' - won't be broken by water, lava, falling entities, make slime blocks slide against them ineffectually, they can float without support just fine - if they were made unmovable by pistons (like e.g. funraces) your only remaining course of action (other than `/setblock <melon position> minecraft:air destroy` ) is to use explosions. TNT exploded on surface of obsidian, 7 blocks away from the melon blocks, but 8 from their stems will break the blocks and leave the stems untouched. Alternatively, creepers (range 5.1 blocks) can be used. Ghast fireballs would work, but managing the explosion radius would be difficult - or you might try a Wither based melon farm, if you're aiming for the awe&fear factor.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This information is false

Melons break when the block below is air.

You can push the block below with a piston to break the melon.

Comment: This didn't work, the launcher also disabled this I guess.

Comment: This information is [wrong](https://imgur.com/X34WojR). In vanilla Minecraft without datapacks melon blocks definitely don't break with the block underneath them removed. Melon stems do, but that's hardly what OP is aiming for.

Comment: @SF. Ok thanks for clarifying. I just assumed it worked when OP said "right, I forgot about its inability to hang in the air. thank you!"